# Json.Net: Turn relations into references and back again (one->many)

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using .NET/[MyCouch](https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch) to read/write plain POCO objects to a NoSQL store (couchdb). This works fine, and also works fine for objects with simple relations.

I would like to express relations as "ids" between types in NoSQL/MyCouch for a project I'm working on, and I'm wanting to learn more about how I would make the most use of JSon.NET for this (MyCouch uses Json.net).

e.g: Login has many Users

```
class Common {
   public string _id; 
   public string _rev;
   ... more here, including ID generation ...
} 

class Login : Common {
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public List<User> users {get;set;}
}

class User : Common {
   public string email {get;set};
}
```

When saving a **User** yields a nested JSON doc:

```
{
   "name": "Neil"
   ...
   "users": [
      {
         "_id": "user:foo:something",
         "_rev": "32-92cca77ee07b8149b8d3dd76f8c8b08d"
         "email": "foo@there.com"
         ...
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

In the normal case, MyCouch (via Json.NET serialization) traverses the relationship and generates nested JSON. Yay.

'Common' is a base class containing the ID, and also stores the ID as a mix of object type:code:UUID (hence the 'user:foo:something' example above).

What I would rather do is generate object IDs to the users, *but only for these kinds of relationships*. Not for every object that inherits from Common (all of them do). I'm pretty sure I could add a converter for all Common objects, but figure that'd break the basic serialization of all objects. I only want to create "lists of IDs" for actual List relationships.

I imagine JSON doc output like this:

```
{
   name: "Neil"
   ...
   users: ["user:foo:something", ... ]
}
```

I can do this by customizing the Json.NET serializer:

```
    [JsonConverterAttribute(typeof(ReferenceListConverter), typeof(User))]
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
```

This works great for output. I get exactly what I want.
Here's ReferenceListConverter:

```
public class ReferenceListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private Type expectedType;

    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override bool CanWrite => true;

    public ReferenceListConverter(Type expectedType)
    {
        this.expectedType = expectedType;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Common).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Get the _id, and _rev, and construct a real object from those
        // In this case, it means making another request to the server.
        var listType = typeof(List<>);
        var list = listType.MakeGenericType(this.expectedType);
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Null)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
                List<string> items = token.ToObject<List<string>>();

                // Construct some items
                // ID's are of form <typename>:<id>
                MethodInfo program = typeof(Program).GetMethod("FetchObjectsFromStore", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
                MethodInfo generic = program.MakeGenericMethod(this.expectedType);

                string[] parameters = items.ToArray();
                var result = generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { parameters });
                return result;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Write out only the ID of the object
        JArray array = new JArray();
        if(value is IEnumerable<Common>)
        {
            foreach (Common item in (IEnumerable<Common>)value)
            {
                array.Add(JToken.FromObject(item._id));
            }
        }
        array.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

1) Reading... is problematic. Basic. But it works for a simple case.

I am unable to inject my "db" class via IoC (I'm using SimpleInjector and havn't figured out how I can inject a specific JsonConverter, for a single field, using IoC).  So ReferenceListConverter uses a static method to do it's subsequent lookups, which is "meh", but OK while I learn.

2) This doesn't take into account cycles. As soon as User <-> Logins, I have an infinite loop.

My question is to knowledgeable Json.NET people: Is there just "a better way" to do this?  Customization of the Json.NET reference mechanisms? Other?